# How to dynamically create and remove a complex div and get input inside it to create dynamic link and textarea?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating a page where i want to create links dynamically. So i am having a button(it calls function fnLink() which dynamically creates popup-div) on click of which it shows a popup-div which asks the name of link to be created. The Popup-div has save and cancel button. On click of save button i need to convert that input text into link and provide some text area to add some description to link then the popup gets removed/hidden. The popup-div is getting created but on click of save it is not creating the link nor textarea neither it is getting removed on click of cancel. Can anybody tell why is this is not working and help me solve the issue? The code was working fine in case of creating one link where i was simply showing and hiding the popup but for creating mulptiple links i am dynamically creating  and removing the popup which is not working!!

```
      $('#link_save_btn').click(function(){
fnLinkSave(); 
    });

    function fnLink($this){
           var $div = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'save_link');
         $div.html('  <input type="text" id="link_header" style="position: 
                absolute; height: 21px;width: 185px;"/>  
                <img id="popup" src="popup.png" style ="position: absolute;"/>   
                <img id="save" src="save.jpg" style="position: absolute;" /> 
                <img id="cancel" src="cancel.jpg" style ="position: absolute;" />');
           $div.appendTo("#page");
           $("#page").trigger('create');        
          }

        function fnLinkSave(){
    // $('#save_link').hide();
    $div.remove(); 
     var l = $('#link_header').val();
     $('<a/>', {href:'#', text: l}).appendTo('#page');  
     var newTextAreaDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextAreaDiv' +
              numTextAreaCounter);
     newTextAreaDiv.html('<textarea rows="1" style=" max-height:100%; max-width: 
        100%; ' + ' id = "textbox' + numTextAreaCounter + ' " autofocus></textarea>');
     newTextAreaDiv.className='notes_textarea';
     newTextAreaDiv.appendTo("#page");
     $("#page").trigger('create');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are removing the $div if you click on the save button. How shall it work then?

```
$div.remove();
```

also, $div is a local variable of another function, make it globally available.

```
var $div;
```

and whithin your function, dont write `var $div =` but simply `$div =`

Comment: It's not removing even. 
And if i remove after creating then also its not working. 
Why this function is not getting called?

Comment: Probably no event listener: Onload in will read the html document, it will add the event listeners to the existing and defined elements. Adding these elements will not have this event listener waiting for it. You have to reassign the specific event listener after creating this div.

Comment: I added the events inside functions. for the first time it works fine. for second time the popup is coming but save and cancel are not working

Comment: please create a jsfiddle if you want further help

Comment: how to add event listeners for thes elements so that each time it works?

Answer (score 1):

I would just make a default popup container of which you can change contents.
So you can store your popup within this div. Which is easy to just .hide() and .show().

For example:

```
function popup(content){
  if ($("#popup").length > 0){ // check if popup div exists
    $("#popup").html(content); // add content to popup div
    $("#popup").show(); // show div, since it exists so its hidden
  }else{
    $("body").append("<div id='popup'>"+content+"</div>"); // if popup not exists make popup
  }
  $("#popup .close").click(function() {$("#popup").hide();});
}
```

Now call:

```
popup("An inputfield: <input type='text' name='inputfield' /><div class='close'>close this div</div>");
```

I don't like removing elements from my document i might need later on, if you dont care you can just .remove(); the object in question.

```
$("#popup .close").click(function() {$("#popup").remove();});
```

Make it a little dynamic, support multiple popups

```
$(".popup .close").click(function() {$(this).parent(".popup").remove();});
```